# facebook login returns code as variable in query string

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am using a Facebook login in one of my website using the sdk for PHP.

Sometimes the facebook login works and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my index.php:

```
/// fb login area.....
include("facebook/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '159326560901256',
  'secret' => 'c6b30bd2f80747b64d5b1d15a3da9e9c',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://xyz.com/login_fb.php'
));

<a href="<?=$loginUrl?>"><img class="fb_img" 
  src="images/fb_logo.png" width="153" height="38" /></a>
```

it goes to `login_fb.php`:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123131231&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxyz.com%2Flogin_fb.php&state=403bc8aaf9eaee4064e3cc27befc71ff&scope=email

now on login_fb.php  i get this url:

```
login_fb.php?code=ASA&S^&*A^S&*A^S&*^A&*ASUAUIYSUIYASIYAUSYUIASA
```

and in `$user` I get `0`

```
/// code for login_fb.php
include("facebook/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '159326560901256',
  'secret' => 'c6b30bd2f80747b64d5b1d15a3da9e9c',
));


// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
      'next' => 'http://minuteville.com/index.php?val=fblogout'
    ));
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: U should remove your app secret or generate it again if you are using the above one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the following line and using `getAccessTokenFromCode` in Facebook SDK, 
the problem can be resolved.

The acesss code expires. So getting new access code by exchanging code resolves the problem

`$access_code = $facebook->getAccessTokenFromCode($_GET['code']);`

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step6

You should be able to build the access token with the code parameter to get the user. It's all written in the doc.

Comment: i have already viewed this .. facebook sdk has built in method getAccessTokenFromCode i am using it its return error 

string(95) "{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has expired.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}" string(216)