# Facebook getLoginUrl returning code variable in URL

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I've been having a tough time trying to get the FB PHP SDK Login functionalities to work properly. The problem is with the login URL, which is not working for me. Upon clicking the link to log in, generated by `

```
//Generate FB log in and log out links
function FBLinks() {
    global $FB;
    if($this->GetFBID()) {
        return 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next='.BASEURL.'/logout.php&access_token='.$FB->getAccessToken();
        } else {
        return $FB->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope'=>'email'));
    }
}`
```

, which generates a link like this one `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1525824323423421&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com%2F&state=b89f0cd22895184a2f0e2f0fe3155d39&scope=email`

and upon clicking it, it takes me to: `http://myurl.com/?code=AQBbMggtb5YxycOEB5BaBWzrqCuTJ6nWokOID4MvoyQ81BtIetAtzVe71dyXI9b6vvXdZ4fLHaMrumraQz2VeU2qcYFr9DbbZQ5ApRHVivUsv3L3h0UbV0X5A3eP34WvBhlNpWVpfm8kxUI8dv8s4XkmzydVIm3BDR71HGv65zV0w-FBEyg97-SLlFxP71iBeNvQCDqZRBVBkxEsjyxdlmqu7tIZGBl0ws4DI2wtrTuuf5DL4iVHq7NPOFomIyfCGt-73t24EbsfzLnq9ezi_U59V938oU9Zi3dEiiGHi7lFezPHT1oILe6CxaVR0Zecyb0&state=b89f0cd22895184a1f0e2f0fe3555d39#_=_`

which shows nothing.

Is there something I need to do with the code variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I read 
[facebook login returns code as variable in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009846/facebook-login-returns-code-as-variable-in-query-string) and seems like the OP had the same problem as me, but couldn't get to work his solution on my end.

Best Regards,
Richi

~~
Reading more about it, seems like I need to exchange that code for an access token somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong and fixed it. The FB code was conflicting with my own code. Thanks for you time everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the official facebook sdk, you don't have to care about the code param - this param is handeld from the sdk's php script.
You just have to use the getUser() function and check for a value($fbid) != 0
After that, you could query  the fb api with wathever you want

```
$fbid = $this->facebook->getUser();

if ($fbid) {
    $profile = $this->facebook->api("/me");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that whenever I click the login link, it gives me the url like ?code=blabla and the page doesn't load. Any idea why then it is not automatically processing code?